# alignment with ordered list

Tags: html, css

i have html here ...

```
<!-- Contact -->
    <section id="volunteer" class="row" data-scroll-factor="0.7">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></div>
        <h1>Volunteer Projects</h1>
        <div class="section-content">
          <p>
          </p>
           <ul class="basiclist">
                       <li>Homeless Shelters and short term respite</li>
                       <li>Addiction & Rehabiliation support</li>
                       <li>Domestic Violence/abuse</li>
                       <li>Asylum Seekers and Refugees</li>
                     </ul>

                     <br><p> If .</p>



        </div>
      </div><!-- End of .col-md-10 -->
    </section><!-- End of Contact-->
```

and my ul is always aligning to the left ... so i tried this css but it isnt working.

```
// Section: volunteer
&#volunteer{

    .basiclist{


            text-align:left;
        }
```

}

so that's it really , not sure what stupid css issue there is although i suspect it is my own stupidity in this instance.  please help.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.

Comment: the ul basically is stuck in the center ... how can i target that specific ul in the section and say align the list in a straight line not centering the text.

Comment: i am using bootstrap so there is some conflict with other parts of the css centering all ul's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the div class=section-content an id of say: myListContainer and then add this CSS rule, it may override the Bootstrap CSS:

```
 #myListContainer { text-align: left; }
```

text-align is not meant to be used directly on the element that you wish to align. It is meant to be applied to a block level element and then the content within that element is affected (inherited).

Comment: right that makes sense but how do i specifcally target the ul ... ? the other content needs to be centered

Comment: that didn't work ....  #volunteer.basiclist{
    
     
     text-align:left;
    }

Comment: It seems like your rule is still targeting the UL, you should be targeting the DIV that contains it. To get the other content centered, give them a class of, say center and then write a CSS class called center that has text-align:center.

Comment: problem with that is that the rest of content then becomes left aligned i only want the ul left aligned

Comment: ok so in simple terms , my ordered list is just simple with bullets... because the text that follows it is center justified the dots are all over the place... how can i align them neatly

Comment: You said you wanted the list on the left and the other content in the center, like this:  https://jsfiddle.net/rkemp0t7/ right?

Comment: yeah just like that looks neat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104126/discussion-between-havingagoatit-and-scott-marcus).

Comment: Remember, text-align is applied to the element that contains the content you actually want aligned. If you want the UL on the left, you apply text-align to its parent, which is the DIV. If you want the paragraph's content (If.) in the center, you apply text-align the the P (the text's parent). This is what an inherited property means - - apply to a parent and the descendants are affected.